# Find the area bounded by $x=-y^2$ and $y=x+2$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area, applications

Question

---

Find the area bounded by $x=-y^2$ and $y=x+2$.

---

My Attempt

---

I know it is a very simple question to ask on MSE, but I don't know why I get stuck.
If you trace the graph, then the point of intersection will be $(-4,2)$ and $(-1,1)$.The problem is that the parabola is not a function, hence it has two corresponding $y$ for one $x$ and I think that's the reason why I get stuck.
I tried it assuming that area between $y^2=x$ and $y=-x+2$, but again got stucked.

I dont know what's troubling me.

Please help.

Comment: Integrate with respect to y.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

In that case is always a good idea to make a sketch

[image]

which suggests an easier calculation by the following set up

$$A=\int_{-2}^1 f(y) dy$$

Comment: I have taken f(y) as y-2-(-y^2) and get the answer in negative can you tell me why ?

Comment: @NewBornMATH Because $y^2 \ge y-2$ therefore to get a positive area we need to consider $f(y)=y^2-(y-2)$.

Comment: Oh i see you have rotated the graph 90 degree right to get the perfect equation...thank you very much.

Comment: @NewBornMATH Yes precisely! You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-2}^{1}\int_{y-2}^{-y^2} dxdy$$